# Spring JPA : @OrderBy doesn't work when using saveAndFlush

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using `@OrderBy` clause on my bean this works fine when i am getting this object from the persistence layer, but when i try to save this data using

```
persistedObject = saveAndFlush(MyCustomObject);
```

Results in `persistedObject` are not sorted as specified by `@OrderBy` clause.

Code snippet :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTION_ID")
@OrderBy("order ASC")
private Set<MySections> sections;
```

```
class MySections {
  // Some Properties
    @Column(name = "SEQ_NO")
    private Integer order;
}
```

**Repository related code**

```
// this brings sections ordered by order property
collectionRepository.findById("123"); 


// Sections in persistedCollection are not ordered
persistedCollection = collectionRepository.saveAndFlush(collection);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `@OrderBy` does not materialize the order directly in database. It fetches the data and performs sorting in memory. To achieve, what you have described you would have to use `@OrderColumn`. It maintains the **persistent** order of rows in database.

One more advice - using just `select` queries is not a good option to check for ordering as database does not assure about the ordering of the result.